# Game of divisors

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Game of divisors: We have number N. On board we write down all divisiors of N. Players choose one of divisors. Lets say d. We erase d and all divisors of d. The player, who erase N, loose.

It was told me that player 2 have winnig strategy. Could you tell me how to show it? Any tips?

Comment: Whoever told you that is wrong, assuming that we only write positive numbers.  For example, suppose $N=7$; the first player erases $1$, leaving only $7$.  The second player now loses.

Comment: @vadim123 you meant $6$ and player 1 choose $2$. (if choosing $1$ is allowed then the game never ends)

Comment: Did you find a single $N$ for which the second player has a winning strategy?  if $N$ is prime then player $1$ just takes $1$.  If $N=p^2$ for prime $p$, so the divisors are $\{1,p,N\}$, then player $1$ takes $p$, removing $1,p$ and leaving just $N$.  If you take $N=pq$, for distinct primes $p,q$,  with divisors $\{1,p,q,N\}$ then player $1$ takes $1$, forcing player $2$ to take either of the two prime factors and then player $1$ takes the other prime factor and wins.  It would be nice if you showed us an example of what you think is generally true.

Comment: @user1952009  Not following.  "we erase $d$ and all divisors of $d$", so if player $1$ chooses $d=1$ then $1$ is erased and can not be chosen again.  Or am I misreading?

Comment: Also see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868440/game-of-replacing-number-with-divisors

Comment: @PM2Ring they are really different games

Comment: @CarryonSmiling: Agreed! Which is why I didn't flag this is a dupe of that other question. But I wanted to link them because I think people interested in one game may also be interested in the other.

Comment: Oh ok, that's nice.

Comment: Possibly the game was described to the OP with the opening move being player 1 freely choosing a number $N$, so that player 2 begins the removal process.  (One minor note:  All results about who has the winning strategy reverse if the game starts with $N=1$.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first player can always win. The idea is kind of cute.

In the first turn player $A$ considers all of the integers $k>1$. If one of them can be deleted so that he has a winning strategy, he deletes it.

If none exist he just deletes $1$, and his opponent is now in a losing position.

---

If you look at the directed graph of the game what happens is that the vertex $I$ of the initial position is connected to a vertex $U$ (the one corresponding to deleting $1$). Such that the neighbours of $U$ are all neighbours of $I$. Every vertex $I$ with this property is a winning position.

Why? Because if $I$ where a losing position, so would be $U$, so $I$ is connected to a losing position, and hence $I$ would be a winning position, a contradiction.

Comment: Very nice, thanks.